# Do duplicate script tags cause multiple runs?

Tags: javascript, client-side-scripting

If I have multiple `<script>` tags pointing to the same Javascript resource, does the browser run once for each `<script>` tag? Or does the browser de-duplicate?

What happens in this case?

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't de-dupe. It's included twice, it's up to the containing code to not redefine itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`example.js` gets run for every time that it is referred to by a script tag**. The browser does not attempt to de-duplicate it. (It may however  request it only once from the server.)

This is true even with `async` and `defer` attributes.

---

If for some reason, you wanted to support duplicate script tags that cause code only to run once, you could a technique similar to [include guards for C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

For instance, `example.js` could contain:

```
if (window.example === undefined) {
  window.example = {
    publicFunction: function publicFunction() {
       // ...
    },
    // ...
  };
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not true for modules, though!